# Android - exception SuperNotCalledException in an Activity where I do call super

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have this exception:

```
android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.problemio/com.problemio.SupportActivity} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3024)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But I have this method in the Activity:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();

    // very important:
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}
```

Why would this exception happen? It seems that I do call super.onDestroy()

Thanks!

Comment: is this a subclass of another class that extends activity? If yes, make sure that class also calls super..

Comment: @deepdroid Sorry, I got a bit confused.  The current activity extends BaseActivity which is a class I made to hold my navigation bar.  Should I add that same super.destroy code to my BaseActivity?

Comment: @Genadinik yes I think that is what you need to do. Because the super that you've posted here is calling BaseActivity.onDestroy() as opposed to Activity.onDestroy() which is ultimately the only one that the system cares about. Adding `super.onDestroy()` to your BaseActivity should fix it.

Comment: @Genadinik, yes, that's what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you guys. Trying it now. Hopefully that will work :)